# Why question becomes commmunity wiki after >10 updates?

Tags: discussion, questions, editing, community-wiki

I often update and save my question to see how it renders, instead of checking it in instant preview. I prefer that way. Also, I often spot single problems in my post and want to correct them immediately. This often result in more than 10 updates which turns my question into community wiki. Then I get up-votes but they do not result in higher reputation.

What is the motivation for that? I'm working on my question to make this place more useful to others but I'm not rewarded for my effort (besides having people answering my clearer question).

Comment: Please justify the down-vote.

Comment: [Voting works different here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences) so don't worry about downvotes on meta too much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There exists a grace period for 5 minutes after the first submit that rolls all edits in that time into the original post so they don't count so you can make those quick minor edits. Otherwise start taking advantage of the instant preview it works great and it seems pretty crazy that you prefer more clicks to format your answer. Also please note that posting a partially complete answer and rapidly editing more and more info is somewhat discouraged behavior as it creates the [fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/203115) problem. As for a Question it's in your best interest to post as good of a question as possible the first time, because once its posted people will start voting on it and you could wind up have a bunch of down-votes or close votes that could have been avoided.

The reason the threshold exists is to prevent people from continually editing their answers/questions which [bumps](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bump/info) them to the top of the page for more rep from upvotes, 10 was decided as a fair number to allow people to benefit from providing meaningful updates and prevent bad people from benefiting too much. Moderators also have the ability to remove CW status, but this is rarely done and generally requires an [exceptional answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3527/31260) that a user has obviously put forth a lot of effort to maintain.

Comment: I was not updating an answer. I was updating a question. And I was updating my question, so getting more reputation for making review was not the reason. You can earn reputation only for revising other people's answers/questions. Anyway, I should probably prepare my question on a side and once I'm clear on what I want to tell, post it, since the process of phrasing a question sometimes takes me more than 5 minutes.

Comment: @dzieciou updated with a bit more question specific info, and its not unheard for some people to type up a question/answer offline and post it later, especially if it long or complicated

Comment: Woah, its now at 10? Guess I haven't been paying attention lately